# Error posting images from web pages using @Url.Content in MVC

Tags: html, model-view-controller

I'm trying to allow users to edit my database by adding images from websites (posting the URL links into a field using the edit view), when trying to deploy my MVC project, I got an error that says a different row in my table cannot be null, it wasn't null, but when I removed this line of code that would present the image on the page, the error went away:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(item.Picture)" height="100" />
```

This is the line of code the error pointed out:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Founder)
```

Comment: What is the `item.Picture` and `item.Founder`? Can you provide additional info for them, also include error details?

Comment: item.Picture and item.Founder represent rows in my table from my database. I made a database for heroes, users can enter their names (e.g. superman), year created, medium and picture (URL link), then it will be displayed on my on the index View.

The error says:

'Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: contentPath'